# log transformation of NON-continuous variable

Tags: data-transformation, continuous-data, discrete-data, logarithm

I try to estimate a log-log specification to obtain an estimate of elasticity. Therefore, I need to log transform my data. My raw control variable is continuous, but my raw dependent variable is in intervals (say, it only takes 6 values: 5000, 6000, 7000,... 100,000).

I know that log transformation is usually applied to continuous variables, so I want to know if the log transformation on the dependent variable (discrete) makes sense?

In the extreme case, if my dependent variable is discrete and has a small variance (e.g. only takes three values 5000, 5500, 6000). Does the coefficient estimate on the log-log specification still give an elasticity interpretation?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does make a sense

Comment: Logarithms are applied to *numbers*.  They neither know nor care how you might choose to characterize the underlying variables or features.

Comment: Logarithms of integers are fine for exactly the same reason as integers 4, 5 and 6 are fine as powers of 10 giving 10000, 100000 and 1000000. Over a small range, however, logarithmic transformation makes little difference any way, as the logarithmic curve and its tangents or secants have similar slope.